# Почему у меня не запускается js, который должен активировать героя

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru"; >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Team Fortress 2 Market</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/core.js" defer></script>
```

а в самом js прописано:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var $hero = jQuerty('#hero'),
   $laser = $hero.find('.laser');

   setInterval( function() {

$hero.removeClass('idle').addClass('attack');

setTimeout( function() {
    $hero.removeClass('attack').removeClass('idle');


}, 3000);

}, 10000);
});
```

Вот сам сайт: http://markettf2.pe.hu/

Сначала чувак должен висеть на месте, а потом, через некоторое время подсвечивать текст, я этого героя взял с сайта: https://anti-captcha.com/

Comment: пишет же jquery не видит, попробуйте версию 1.11

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, ты тоже невнимательна как и автор. читай по буквам что именно не видит :-) _jQuer**t**y is not defined_

Comment: @Grundy, точно! =))))